# How to add PHP Session variable into FormData using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, form-data

I'd like to pass a PHP session variable (called 'profileid') using FormData and AJAX.  I thought this below would work, it did not.  Why?

```
var imageData = new FormData();
imageData.append('image', $('#uploadImage')[0].files[0]);
imageData.append('profileid', <?php echo $_SESSION['profileid'];?>);

//Make ajax call here:
$.ajax({
      url: '/upload-image-results-ajax.php',
      type: 'POST',
      processData: false, // important
      contentType: false, // important
      data: imageData,
      //leaving out the rest as it doesn't pertain
```

Comment: on the server side try to `var_dump($_POST)` to see all the data you have sent and then console log the response in the success function.

Comment: what does it return in response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the profileid in the `$.ajax` URL parameter instead of adding it in FormData:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('#uploadImageForm').on('submit',(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData(this);

        $.ajax({
            url: "/upload-image-results-ajax.php?profileid=<?= $_SESSION['profileid']; ?>",
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(response){
                console.log("success");
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(response){
                console.log("error");
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    }));

    $('#uploadImage').on("change", function() {
        $("#uploadImageForm").submit();
    });
});
```

Don't forget to place `session_start();` at the beginning of your code.

Comment: This worked with @Grover's changes. I know what you changed Grover, but what is that exactly? Some sort of shorthand?  I've never seen it before.